# How to refactor this 'command handler map' from derived classes to the base class?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, refactoring, typedef

I am trying to refactor some C++ code by moving certain common functionality from derived classes to the base class.  Say I have a base class `Fruit` and two derived classes `Apple` and `Orange`.  Both derived classes currently hold a private map that maps commands to member functions, e.g. for the `Apple` class this would be

```
typedef void (Apple::*CommandHandler)();
static const std::map<std::string, CommandHandler> commandhandlers;
```

As the `commandhandlers` map does not change over time, I've made it static and for each derived class it gets filled with commandhandlers using a static function, e.g. for the `Apple` class:

```
static std::map<std::string, Apple::CommandHandler> mpInitCommandHandlerMap()
{
    std::map<std::string, Apple::CommandHandler> commandhandlers;
    commandhandlers.insert(std::make_pair("eat", &Apple::eat));
    // ... and so on...
    return commandhandlers;
}
```

where

```
void eat() { std::cout << "eating apple" << std::endl; }
```

is an example of a (private) command handler for the `eat` command in the `Apple` class.

Both the `Apple` and the `Orange` derived classes also have a `handle` function to handle different commands:

```
void handle(const std::string& command)
{
    const auto handler = commandhandlers.at(command);
    (this->*handler)();
}
```

Since this `handle` function is the same for both derived classes, I want to move it to the `Fruit` class.  However, that is where I'm stuck.  The `commandhandlers` map currently exists in both the `Apple` and the `Orange` class, and with different types for the command handler functions (`typedef void (Apple::*CommandHandler)();` for the `Apple` class and `typedef void (Orange::*CommandHandler)();` for the `Orange` class).

So my question is: I want to have only one `commandhandler` map and one `handle` function in the `Fruit` class.  How do I do this (preferably using C++14 for now)?  The full code is available online at https://godbolt.org/z/87zbGa

Comment: Place `std:map<std:string, std::function<void()> > commandhandlers_;` in your base class and initialize it normally in your `Apple` or `Orange` constructors: `commandhandlers_["eat"] = std::bind(&Apple::eat, this);`

Comment: @pptaszni This may conflict with the requirement to have a `static` command handlers map. Otherwise, `Apple` may "see" the commands of `Orange`.

Comment: "may see the commands of `Oragne`" - I don't think it is possible. `Apple::Apple(params ... )` will populate the map with the commands only `Apple` may know, and vice versa. Show me some example if I am wrong. The requirement to have `static` maps in derived classes conflicts a bit with being able to call that map from the base class.

Comment: Two more remarks:

1) Note that in the long term, the Fruit class will also add command handlers to the command handler map.  Those will be command handler functions defined in the Fruit class (= same behavior for the Apple and Orange classes).

2) I'm not completely sure whether indeed the command handler map needs to be static or not...  In any case, Apple command handlers should not get confused with Orange command handlers!

Comment: Yes, considering your remarks, I still think that my suggested solution is what you need.You don't need to worry about confusing Apple and Orange commands, in case of `fruit->handle("apple_specific_command");` invoked on the object of type `Orange` the key `apple_specific_command` will not be in the `commandhandlers_` map.

Answer (score 1):

You might factorize with CRTP, something like:

```
template <typename Derived>
class Fruit
{
public:
    void handle(const std::string& command)
    {
        const auto handler = commandhandlers.at(command);
        (static_cast<Derived*>(this)->*handler)();
    }

protected:
    using CommandHandler = void (Derived::*)();
    static const std::map<std::string, CommandHandler> commandhandlers;
};

template <typename Derived>
const std::map<std::string, typename Fruit<Derived>::CommandHandler>
Fruit<Derived>::commandhandlers = Derived::mpInitCommandHandlerMap();
```

and then

```
class Apple : public Fruit<Apple>
{
friend class Fruit<Apple>;
private:
   
    static std::map<std::string, CommandHandler> mpInitCommandHandlerMap()
    {
        return {
            {"eat", &Apple::eat}
            // ... and so on...
        };
    }

    void eat() { std::cout << "eating apple" << std::endl; }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6ndh9K)

I dropped common base class between `Apple` and `Orange` that you can reintroduce if needed.

Comment: It is very interesting solution.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the command handler map and the handle function to the Fruit base class as

```
class Fruit
{
public:
    
    void handle(const std::string& command)
    {
        const auto handler = commandhandlers_.at(command);
        handler();
    }

protected:
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> commandhandlers_;
};
```

and then initializing the command handler map in the derived classes, e.g. for Apple as

```
    Apple()
    {
        commandhandlers_ = mpInitCommandHandlerMap();
    }
```

where `mpInitCommandHandlerMap` is non-static seems to work.  See also full solution at https://godbolt.org/z/jx1cs8

Comment: One small downside here: the commandhandlers_ map does not change over time, so I want to make it const, but that is not possible because it gets its initial value in the Apple constructor.  When trying to initialize in the initializer list of Apple, the compiler of course complains that Apple does not have a field name commandhandlers_ :-(

Comment: Nope, there is no downside here. Just initialize the map in constructor initializer list and you are fine. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/q3GEbE)

Comment: OK, one can indeed take the map as a parameter for the Fruit constructor.  Thanks.